# Add gesture recognizer to UISlider min/max value image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer, uislider

I need to add touch response to the min and max value images for a `UISlider`. The slider is a zoom bar so the images are a minus and plus and if touched, they should zoom in or out accordingly. The `UISlider` properties `minimumValueImage` and `maximumValueImage` are of type `UIImage`, not `UIImageView` so I cannot add a gesture recognizer directly to it.

Any ideas? Is the only option to get hacky and make clear buttons on top of the images? If that's the case, how can I get the min/max image frames?

Answer (score 0):

The image views you are looking for are inside the @package in **UISlider** class and not accessible from outside

`UIImageView *_minValueImageView;`
`UIImageView *_maxValueImageView;`

You can still get them using objective c runtime.

`#import <objc/runtime.h>`

```
// Initialize slider and images
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 40)];
[slider setMinimumValueImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"]];
[slider setMaximumValueImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2"]];

Ivar minimumValueImageViewIvar = class_getInstanceVariable([slider class], "_minValueImageView");
UIImageView *minimumValueImageView =  (UIImageView*)( object_getIvar(slider, minimumValueImageViewIvar) );
// [minimumValueImageView setHidden:YES];

Ivar maximumValueImageViewIvar = class_getInstanceVariable([slider class], "_maxValueImageView");
UIImageView *maximumValueImageView =  (UIImageView*)( object_getIvar(slider, maximumValueImageViewIvar) );
// [maximumValueImageView setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the subviews of the slider. There should be 2 UIImageView. You can then set userInteractionEnabled=YES and add a UITapGestureRecognizer to each of them.

```
NSMutableArray* images = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id sv in slider.subviews) {
   if ([sv isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
       [image addObject:sv];
   }
}
if (images.count == 2) {
    UITapGestureRecognizer* gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                         action:@selector(minImageTapped:)];
    [imageViews[0] addGestureRecognizer:gr];
    [imageViews[0] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 action:@selector(maxImageTapped:)];
    [imageViews[1] addGestureRecognizer:gr];
    [imageViews[1] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of GenesisST's answer:

```
let images:[UIView] = outsSlider.subviews.filter({$0 is UIImageView})

if (images.count == 2) {
    let tapMin = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(minImageTapped));
    let tapMax = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(maxImageTapped));
    images[0].addGestureRecognizer(tapMin)
    images[1].addGestureRecognizer(tapMax)
    images[0].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    images[1].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```